# How to expire an otp after a certain time- Flask Python

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am developing a web app using flask. In the web app's login page I'm sending One Time Password(otp) to the user generated using pyotp module and storing it in the database. 
My problem is that, I want to expire the otp after say 30 minutes if the user has not logged in using that otp, but I don't know what is the best way to do it. I'm fairly new to flask and web development. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the OTP in the database, then you can add the `expires_at` or any other suitable named column. This also means that you have to periodically remove the expired keys.

In case you are using Redis as storage, this can be dealt by marking stored passwords as [autoexpiring](http://redis.io/commands/expire).